# SQL Alter Table then Modify Values

Tags: sql, alter-table

I have a SQL script that I am working on and I run into an issue when I'm creating (or editing) a column and then attempting to modify that new column.

For example:

```
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE SampleTable ADD ColumnThree int 
END

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'ColumnThree'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE SampleTable SET ColumnThree = 0
END
```

Now I thought the BEGIN/END blocks would separate those two items out, but I get an error "Invalid column name 'ColumnThree'." when I attempt to run this.  Why?  Shouldn't the first BEGIN/END set up that ColumnThree and more to the point the IF(EXISTS should protect the UPDATE statement from being run if that column name doesn't exist.

What is the correct way to do something like this?  (I seem to have a couple of similar scenarios where this is needed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`GO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx), not `BEGIN/END`. Also, you may want to edit your `EXISTS` query a bit to ensure you're getting the right table:

```
ALTER TABLE SampleTable ADD ColumnThree int 
GO

IF (EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1 
         FROM 
             sys.columns c 
             INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON 
                 c.object_id = t.object_id 
         WHERE 
             t.name = 'SampleTable' 
             AND c.name = 'ColumnThree'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE SampleTable SET ColumnThree = 0
END
```

If you're using multiple schemas, you will want to through `sys.schemas` into the check, as well.

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is great for checking if columns exist

Comment: @Russ: You keep your portable solutions to yourself! :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much ... also works as (in the event there are multiple items in the first BEGIN/END):

BEGIN
 ALTER TABLE SampleTable ADD ColumnThree int 
END
GO

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'ColumnThree'))
BEGIN
 UPDATE SampleTable SET ColumnThree = 0
END

Comment: @Chris: No need to wrap them in `begin...end`. They're only necessary with other statments (`while`, `if`, etc.). `GO` will execute the pending batch of transactions, regardless of whether or not they're wrapped in `begin...end`. That being said, if `begin...end` makes your code more readable, by all means use it!